# C++: Custom 'List' Member Functions

Tags: c++, list

I have an index table where every index contains a list of type 'entry', where entry is

```
class entry{
    public:
        string word;
        vector<int> line_numbers;
}
```

List member functions such as 'push_back' and 'empty' are unrecognized by the compiler since the list is of a custom type. How should I format to make these work, short of expanding the 'entry' class to include modified list member functions? Is that even possible? For reference,

```
vector<list<entry> > table
```

is the index table, and

```
table[c]
```

is the index. I'm trying to use something akin to

```
table[c].empty()
```

to test if the list is empty.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector<std::vector<Entry>>`?

Comment: AFAIK the code you have shown should work.  Please provide a complete, minimal, self-contained example that fails to compile in the manner described.

Comment: Using a vector would certainly be easier, but I'm trying to learn how to use embedded lists. In the past when I've used embedded lists they've been of a simple datatype like 'int', but now I'm trying to use a custom one.

Comment: What is an embedded list?

Comment: I always thought an embedded list was when you have a linked list wired right into a class. E.g. `struct Foo { string name; Foo* next; /* ... */ };`

Comment: By embedded I mean nested. I'm sorry if I confused anyone with that

Comment: I wouldn't call this "nested", either. There's nothing special about `list` here, and you wouldn't be talking about "embedded" or "nested" ints either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mistaken. `std::list<entry>::empty()` works regardless of the definition of `empty`. `push_back` requires that you can copy (or move) an `empty` object, how else are you going to get it into the container?

Comment: You're right. I just deleted and retyped the exact same code and now 'empty' works.

Comment: However, I'm still having trouble with push_back. The error message reads: 

    'no matching function for call to std::list<index_table::entry>::push_back(const string&)'

Comment: @user2876980: That's a fairly obvious message: You are pushing a string onto a list of entries. That obviously won't work in a typesafe language like C++.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Since each node of the list contains a word and a vector of integers, should I have push_back(string, vector<int>)?

Comment: @user2876980: No, that would be `.emplace_back(word, lineNumbers)`. `.push_back()` assumes you already have an entry object.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you!